# Associating a new object with an existing object with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two classes Users and Projects. A user can own many projects and a project can be owned by many users. However, a project must have at least one user while a user does not necessary have to have a project.

This is what I currently have:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :prj_id, :name
    has_many :ownerships, foreign_key: "project_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :ownerships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

    has_many :ownerships, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :projects, through: :ownerships
    validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }
    validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end

class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :project_id

    belongs_to :user, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :project, class_name: "Project"

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :project_id, presence: true
end
```

Thus, a user must exist first before we can create a project. What I am currently having trouble is with is when I try to create a new project and append users to the new project, it does not allow me to save because the user already exists in the User table. More specifically, in the rails console:

```
>> prj = Project.new(prj_id: 'hello', name: 'hello')
>> usr = User.find_by_id(1)
>> prj.users<<usr
>> prj.save
```

The prj.save line fails giving this message:

```
(0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('example@example.com') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> false
```

Is there a way to associate the new project with existing user(s), creating a new entry in both the Project table and Ownership table while checking if the user exists in the User table (and not try to create a new user)? Thanks!

Comment: Try inspecting your `prj.errors` and `usr.errors` after calling `prj.save`. Are there any error messages? Also, what does your `Ownership` table/model look like?

Comment: The errors is just that the user is invalid because it is trying to save to the User table (and fails the uniqueness validation). Ownership is just a table with user_id and project_id as foreign keys from the User table and the Project table, respectively. What I want is to create a new Project and new Ownership tuples that reference existing users and the new project. I want to save the new Project and the new Ownership tuples, but not the users, since they already exist.

Comment: Where is your ownership class? Does it have any validations?

Comment: Sounds like you have more than one user with the email address 'example@example.com'

Comment: I've updated the post with the Ownership class.

Comment: There is initially one user with the email 'example@example.com' and I want to create a Project entry in the Project table that references the user in the Ownership table (and perhaps more users). I do not want to create new User objects, but the problem is that when I do a save on my new project, it also saves to the User table even though the user I associated with it already exists there. i.e. I want to make sure that the user_id I am adding to the Ownership table exists in the User table before saving to the Ownership and Project tables, but I do not want to save to the User table.

Answer (score 0):

Your project's *ownership* record is invalid because it requires the presence of a `project_id`, which is `nil` for a new project. You'll either need to create the project first or change the validation in your `Ownership` model.

You can see this by inspecting the errors object of the models involved:

```
> prj.errors.full_messages
=> ["Ownerships is invalid"]
> prj.ownerships.first.errors.full_messages
=> ["Project can't be blank"]
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to do it atomically so that if one fails the other one also fails as well. I would not like a dangling Project other if the system somehow fails to create an Ownership tuple.

Comment: I personally wouldn't validate `user_id` and `project_id` on your Ownership. These are the only restrictions preventing the Ownership from being created and they don't really gain you much since Rails is handling the creation for you through the association. Validation is useful for cases where the user can make corrections... they don't appear to be directly editing the Ownership in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your validation on the `ownership` class to

```
validates :user, presence: true
validates :project, presence: true
```

Not sure if the distinction of validating the actual association (`project`) vs the id (`project_id`)  will make a difference, but it's worth trying. That said, if you're creating the associations from the project side (and projects must always have a user but not the other way) it sounds by your business rules that you only *really* need the user side of the validation anyway.